# Laravel deleting a file NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

this is my form in my view

```
         {!! Form::open(['url' => ['documents/{file}/{id}', $file->name, $file->id],'method' => 'delete']) !!}
         {!! Form::token() !!}
         {!! Form::submit('Delete') !!}
         {!! Form::close() !!}
```

controller in which i delete file from database and the original file

```
public function destroyFile($file_name, $id)
{
    File::findOrFail($id)->delete();
    $file_path = storage_path('documents').'/'.$file_name;
    $destinationPath = $file_path; File::delete($file_path);
    return redirect('/documents');
}
```

This is the route

```
Route::delete('documents/{file}/{id}','FilesController@destroyFile');
```

And when i press submit button I get NotFoundHttpException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'action' => ['FilesController@destroyFile', $file->name, $file->id] ]) !!}
```

Actually, their answers are correct. You need the _method to be DELETE. When I am using this. Laravel do it for me.

Or you can put this on your form

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
```

or

```
{!! Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE') !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use this method with html forms in most browsers, most only support `GET` and `POST`.
So the reason for this request not working is because the browser sends this as a GET request, wich is the default.

`GET`, `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` are however supported in most major browsers when using XMLHttpRequests (ajax).

Answer (score 0):

add `{{ method_field('DELETE') }}` to your form .

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => ['documents/{file}/{id}', $file->name, $file->id],'method' => 'delete']) !!}
{{ method_field('DELETE') }}
{!! Form::token() !!}
{!! Form::submit('Delete') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that HTML forms does not support PUT, PATCH, DELETE actions. Basically you need to spoof them as described here. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#form-method-spoofing